# How to get the text field line in uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

\I want to remove the border black line. I need to keep only rounded text fields. with also the uiview. How to do that?

Adding the uialert with the two alert things.

Question edited for

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `UIAlertController` will not currently support the appearance that you want. Those text fields were meant to have rectangular corners.

- While the `UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect` style can be applied, there is no support in the class for customizing the private aspects of the `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert` style that are responsible for the outer border.
- Even a `UIAlertController` subclass is not an option.

The documentation is clear on these points.

> ### Subclassing
>
> **The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.** The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

To get the appearance you want will require you to use a different class.